# How to open a file for writing that other processes can read?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, file-io

I want to have my program open a text file for logging.  While my program is running (and writing to / updating the file) I would like to be able to open the file in another program (notepad, ultraedit, whatever) and see everything that has currently been written to the file.

I tried using `_fsopen` with `_SH_DENYWR`, and while I can indeed open the log file, the file is blank / size 0 until my program exits.  What am I missing?

Comment: hmm, yep -- looks like that will do it.  That or use `setvbuff`.  Thanks.